# RoR - check presence in has_many polimorphic reference in the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am making an app with User, Submissions and Comments. I need both the submissions and comments to have a Like button, so after some researching I finally created a Like model, using the reference to user and a polimorphic reference to Submission and Comment. As I am new in RoR, I share the code I have so you can correct me if there is something wrong:

guser.rb:

```
class Guser < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :likes, dependent: :destroy
end
```

like.rb:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guser
  belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true
end
```

submission.rb:

```
class Submission < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :guser
  has_many :comments
  ... 
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  has_many :likers, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

comment.rb:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...  
  has_many :likes, as: :likeable
  has_many :likers, through: :likes, source: :user
end
```

migration create_likes:

```
class CreateLikes < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :likes do |t|
      t.integer :likeable_id
      t.string  :likeable_type
      t.references :guser, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Now my question is: I need to only show the like button if the submission/comment has not been already liked by the user. So now I need to do something like this:

```
<%if current_guser and not current_guser.likes.map(&:submission_id).include? submission.id %>
      <%= link_to(image_tag("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/7/7f/Green_equilateral_triangle_point_up.svg/1182px-Green_equilateral_triangle_point_up.svg.png", :width => 8, :height => 8), { :controller => "likes", :submission_id => submission.id,:action => "create"}, method: :post) %>
```

But now I need to check if the likeable_type is submission and the likeable_id matches with the submission id. And, in the comments view I must do the same but with the comments. How can I do this check? Is there any includes function for a map with more than one attribute?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
<% if current_guser and not current_guser.likes.
        map{|x| [x.likeable_id, x.likeable_type]).
        include? [submission.id, 'Submission'] %>
```

or, you can search for the full object:

```
<% if current_guser and not current_guser.likes.map(&:likeable).
      include?(submission) %>
```

Note that for the latter option, you may want to use `includes` in your controller action to make sure you avoid `N+1` queries:

```
@user_likes = Like.includes(:likeable).where(guser_id: current_guser.id)
```

Another option you may want to consider is to have a hash lookup (O(1) for looking up a key) instead of running multiple `include?` statements (O(N) every time you're looking for a key). 
E.g.:

```
# app/models/guser.rb
class Guser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # @return [Hash] of the structure { ['Submission', 5] => <Like object> }
  def self.lookup_for_user(guser_id)
    # With `pluck` no active record objects are created, saving some overhead
    arr = where(guser_id: guser_id).pluck(:likeable_type, :likeable_id).map{|x| [x, true]}
    Hash[arr]
  end
end

# app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def your_action
  @user_likes_lookup = Like.lookup_for_user(current_guser.id)
end
```

And then all you need to do in the view is something like:

```
<% if current_guser and not @user_likes_lookup[['Submission', submission.id]] %>
```

Finally, note that as your system grows and number of likes per user become large, these are not very performant methods, since you're loading all the likes a person made. You may want to then consider restricting the database query to pull only the Submission and Comment ids that you are rendering on your page.

E.g., you may change the `Guser::lookup_for_user` to this:

```
# app/models/guser.rb
class Guser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # @return [Hash] of the structure { ['Submission', 5] => <Like object> }
  def self.lookup_for_user(guser_id, likeable_objects_to_find=[])
    arr = where(guser_id: guser_id, likeable: likeable_objects_to_find).pluck(:likeable_type, :likeable_id).map{|x| [x, true]}
    Hash[arr]
  end
end
```

And then in your controller:

```
# app/controllers/your_controller.rb
def your_action
  @submissions = # ... || []
  @comments = # ... || []
  @user_likes_lookup = Like.lookup_for_user(current_guser.id, @submissions + @comments)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved kind of the same problem by adding the following method to a likeable model (a Post or Comment in my case):

```
  def is_liked_by user
    if defined? user
      self.likes.find_by(user: user) # likes referes to the relation declaration: has_many :likes, :as => :likeable, :dependent => :destroy
    else 
      false
    end
  end
```

You should customize it for your own User model of course.

Check if someone liked a post by using this in your view:

```
unless likeable.is_liked_by current_user
  # do your magic
else
  # do some other stuff (like unlike :))
end
```